# Working with a precompiled VB.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, precompiled

I am working with a precompiled ASP.net website.  I have most of the *.aspx.vb files, but I am missing some of the library files, and only have the DLLs.  Can I still selectively compile aspx.vb files?  When I just hit build, It errors with 'This application is already precompiled'

Comment: Can you simply add references to those compiled DLLs from a project that contains your .vb files, and then build that project?

Comment: it all depends... you're leaving out alot of information, like if all the compiled assemblies are merged into one or if each .vb files is in their own .dll. And if the website is updatable or not.

Comment: It looks like a 1 to 1 relationship with VB to DLLs.  There are many DLLs of the files that I do not have access to the VB.  I do not know how to tell if the website is updatable.

Comment: Brad - how would I do that?  (I'm a LAMP programmer usually, so I'm a bit clueless with the tools)

Answer (score 1):

If you have DLLs, then most likely those are external assemblies which are not part of the project, to which the source files belong. So if you have a project file, try compiling it and see if it reports missing *source* (.vb) files. Most likely compiler will give you hints regarding particular problems.

If you don't have a project file, the situation becomes more complicated. You might need to use some decompiler tool (9rays.net decompiler is a good one) to restore the source files from compiled DLL (note - main project DLL, not those library DLLs) and analyze what's missing and what was included.

Comment: I do not have the project file, but I have the vb for all of the files that I need to edit.  Do I still need the decompiler?

Comment: @Jonathan the question is whether you can properly recreate the project file and it's options and configuration. If you can, that's great.

Comment: Okay, I've relinked all of the DLLS and their refresh URIs, so the only error I get is that it is precompiled.  How can I tell it that it knows enough to rebuild?

Comment: @Jonathan I am sorry but it's impossible to tell anything in this format. This is the task you probably need to deal with locally yourself.